# getpixel()is showing error

Tags: android, getpixel

i am  using an image view in which i want to know the pixel color so i am using getpixel()...
method 
but it is showing me an error ....
this is the way i am using get pixel method..

```
image  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), rid);
                pixel = image.getPixel((int)x,(int)y);
                k.setText(Integer.toString(pixel));
```

it is showing me an error.......

```
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at com.example.nam.FirstImage.pageinfo(FirstImage.java:100)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at com.example.nam.FirstImage.onTouch(FirstImage.java:63)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3881)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1769)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1135)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1753)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2227)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1886)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-24 13:29:38.101: E/AndroidRuntime(21987):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**edit ::::**

```
public class FirstImage extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener {


    MotionEvent event;
    TextView k;
    int rid;
    int pixel;
    Bitmap image;
    String huma ="human";
    String info = "human";
     float x = 0; //init value 
     float y = 0; //init value
     Animation animationFadeIn;
    int t=0;
    int i=1;

    public FirstImage(Context context) { 
        super(context); 
        k=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);



        } 
    public FirstImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
        super(context, attrs);
        k=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        } 


    public void changeImage(int id){

                    this.setImageResource(id);
                rid=id;
                    final Animation animationFadeout=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.zoomin);
                    this.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                    this.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent me) {

        switch(me.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x=me.getX();
            y= me.getY();
            pageinfo(x,y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            x=me.getX();
            y= me.getY();
            pageinfo(x,y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            x=me.getX();
            y= me.getY();
            pageinfo(x,y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            x=me.getX();
            y= me.getY();
            pageinfo(x,y);
            break;
        default: return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void pageinfo(float x, float y) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         if(rid==R.drawable.cell){
                image  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), rid);
                pixel = image.getPixel((int)x,(int)y);
                k.setText(Integer.toString(pixel));

                }
}
```

Comment: which line is line 100? Are you sure that rid is a valid bitmap resource id?

Comment: yes i am storing the value in that of R.drawble.imge. the line no 100 is k.setText(Integer.toString(pixel));

Comment: Integer.toString is not returning null so that means that k must be null.

Comment: So then either `k` or `pixel` is throwing the exception. If that's the case, then no, `getPixel()` isn't throwing the error if it's not on line 100 where the exception is originating from. We need more.

Comment: My guess is that `k` hasn't been instantiated yet.

Comment: ok i am pasting my whole class there ..

Comment: did you checked that "image  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), rid);" returned image is not equal to null?

Comment: what do you mean ? i am not understanding you ?

Comment: try inserting `Log.i("test", k.toString);` above the line where the error occurs and tell us what the console outputs

Comment: @Pieter888 it is not displaying anything in console

Comment: @Ashishsingh Nothing? Is the code not being reached?

Comment: nothing means after starting the activty it is not dispalying anything .

Comment: Maybe the console has been paused? How about a `Toast`? Just make sure you know the state of all your relevant objects at the time of the error.

Comment: @Pieter888 iam not getting you ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11677/discussion-between-pieter888-and-ashishsingh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because your `k` member is `null`;

It is declared and used an `ImageView` extendsion, and initialized using `findViewById` which returns back `null`. 
Using the same code (`findViewById`) from within the parent `Activity` gives back the desired `TextView` instance.

You should remove the `k` member from your `FirstImage` class, and when you get the `pixel` value at an `onTouch` event, pass it to the `Activity`: let it handle the other gui stuff:

So change your `FirstImage` as:

```
pixel = image.getPixel((int)x,(int)y);
((AshActivity) getContext()).writePixelIntoK(pixel);
```

and implement the `writePixelIntoK` method inside your main activity, e.g.:

```
public void writePixelIntoK(int pixel)
{
    k.setText("pixel touched: " + pixel);
}
```